# Unclosed brackets highlight color in Vim

Tags: vim, highlight, brackets

How can I customize the highlight color for the unclosed bracket in Vim?
This is how Vim highlights an unclosed bracket when the cursor is **not** over the same line as the bracket:

[image]

This is nice, but when I move the cursor over the line where the bracket lies, this is how it looks:

[image]

Now, I barely can see where the bracket is. How can I change this? By the way, I'm using `:set cursorline` option to highlight the current line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `CursorLine` highlight group has more "weight" than other highlight groups, including `Error` which can lead to that kind of situation where the background color of `Error` is overruled.

The solution I've found while working on [my colorscheme](http://romainl.github.io/Apprentice/) is to set the foreground and background colors of `Error` to the inverse of what I want: red on black vs black on red and use the `reverse` value for `cterm` and `gui`:

```
hi Error ctermbg=NONE ctermfg=131 guibg=NONE guifg=#af5f5f cterm=reverse gui=reverse
```

And make sure `CursorLine` doesn't set any foreground color:

```
  hi CursorLine ctermbg=236 ctermfg=NONE guibg=#303030 guifg=NONE cterm=NONE gui=NONE
```

It works pretty well:

[image: Error]

You'll need to edit the colorscheme you are using and, if possible, send a pull request to its author.

Comment: I [had always wished for a difference precedence of cursorline and syntax background](http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/46c70a229488de20), but your nifty trick almost completely makes up for this. Thanks! (Only downside is that the Windows console doesn't support the reverse attribute.)